# EJB lookup problem

Tags: glassfish, ejb

I have a Glassfish v2.1.1 cluster setup. I deployed an EAR file consisting a single stateless bean to stand alone server. It has an IIOP port 3752.

My client application which will be communicating with this bean is deployed on cluster. When i lookup bean's name, i get NameNotFoundException. Code looks as below:

```
Properties props = new Properties();

props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial",    "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");

props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "com.sun.enterprise.naming");

props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.state", "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");


if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {

  logger.debug("Looking for bean from location : " + PropertiesService.instance().getSchedulerOrbHost() + ":"

                + PropertiesService.instance().getSchedulerOrbPort());

}


props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost",     PropertiesService.instance().getSchedulerOrbHost());

props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort",     PropertiesService.instance().getSchedulerOrbPort());


InitialContext context = null;


try {

context = new InitialContext(props);

} catch (NamingException e) {

e.printStackTrace();

}

String beanName = "test.OperationControllerRemote";

OperationControllerRemote remote = (OperationControllerRemote) context.lookup(beanName);
```

Note that i checked JNDI tree and name "test.OperationControllerRemote" is there.

Any opinions please?

Comment: I think it's `appclient -targetserver`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the ways I have got it to work with a GF 2.1.1 cluster and a Swing client.  I'm currently going with the Standalone option because of client launch speed, but the ACC might work for you.

#### Standalone

The way you're doing it is considered standalone.

http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#StandaloneRemoteEJB

http://blogs.oracle.com/dadelhardt/entry/standalone_iiop_clients_with_glassfish

#### ACC

Another way to approach this is to launch the client with the ACC.  This means packaging the client code into the ear as an Application Client and either launching using the JNLP method or manually installing a bundled ACC (mini glassfish really) on client machines.  In GF 2.1, either way works ok, but both are pretty fat and JNLP method can make startup times a bit longer.  Supposedly in GF 3.1 they've reworked the ACC and it starts up faster.  Something that may not be obvious is that with the ACC you get the list of servers in the cluster provided automatically at client startup.

http://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/java_ee_clients_with_or

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beakv.html#scrolltoc

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/gkusn.html

#### Lookups

Either of the above ways provides RMI/CORBA failover and load balancing for the client.

Either way, when you have the right dependencies on your classpath and the `com.sun.appserv.iiop.endpoints` system property set (like node1:33700,node2:33701), you'll only need the no-args InitialContext because Glassfish's stuff autoregisters their connection properties, etc as described in the first link:

```
new InitialContext()
```

And lookups will work.  For my remote session beans (EJB 3.0) I typically do it like:

```
@Stateless(mappedName="FooBean")
public class FooBean implements FooBeanRemote {}

@Remote
public interface FooBeanRemote {}
```

then in client code:

```
FooBeanRemote foo = (FooBeanRemote) ctx.lookup("FooBean");
```

Comment: My client application is deployed on cluster and EJB is deployed on stand alone server. When i look up the bean from remote machines using stand alone clients, the result is success. When i lookup from cluster, it fails. I think there is another trick here.

Comment: Maybe this thread will point you in the right direction: http://www.mentby.com/Group/glassfish-users/remote-server-bean-call.html  It seems you'll need a jndi name like "corbaname:iiop:1.2@192.68.9.10:3700#AccountControllerBean"  also: http://home.java.net/node/657009